# Where are the files in a bare repository?

Tags: git, github

So, I cloned a project to a bare repository on a remote server thinking I could use that as the remote file structure which to run my site off. Running `git clone --bare http://github.com/myproject` only created a directory called `myproject.git`.

I get some of the functions of a bare repository, but where is the file structure of my project within it?

If it can be used to run code off of (I may be incorrect in this assumption), then I need somewhere to point to as my webserver document root.

At present, I cannot find any of my files within the bare repository.

Answer (score 13):

They are stored as "*blobs*" in the `.git/` directory and they are totally unreachable as "files".

To get a visible version of your project, you should clone it and extract it from the bare repository.

In fact, the first usage of the bare repository is to have it on servers, in a place where it is quite unlikely that a user will come and start using the files.

I hope it answers to your questions.

Comment: That's a pretty good answer, should be the acceptable one!

Answer (score 4):

Bare repositories are "bare", quite surprisingly :-) This means that they are "empty", and do not have a checked out file structure. (There are files that record git history, though.)

That being said, in later versions of Git, (2.5+) you can always add another worktree. This works with bare repositories as well. See the documentation for more information.

Comment: Well in his/her case you are wrong, the --bare repository is not empty, it just stores all the information as "blobs" (binary objects) this is why he can't find the file structure of the project.

An empty --bare repo would be `git init --bare` but he clearly clones something.

Comment: @babaliaris I edited my answer to qualify my answer.